# How to convert objects into array using serialization API?

Tags: services, dependency-injection

I'm trying to convert entity objects into array but it's not working. Can you please help me spotting the mistake. I need to use `serializer.normalizer.content_entity' service. The code I have written is:

```
class ComplexMergeResolver implements ConflictResolverInterface {

  protected $serializer;

  protected function setUp() {
    $this->serializer = $this->container->get('serializer.normalizer.content_entity');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function applies() {
   return TRUE;
  }

  /**
   * @param RevisionableInterface $revision1
   * @param RevisionableInterface $revision2
   * @param RevisionableInterface $revision3
   *
   * @return array
   */
  public function merge(RevisionableInterface $revision1, RevisionableInterface $revision2, RevisionableInterface $revision3) {
    $r1_array = $this->serializer->normalize($revision1, 'array');
    $r2_array = $this->serializer->normalize($revision2, 'array');
    $r3_array = $this->serializer->normalize($revision3, 'array');
    $merge = new ThreeWayMerge();
    $result = $merge->performMerge($r1_array, $r2_array, $r3_array);
    return $result;
  }
}
```

`r1_array` is returned empty, which means `normalize` method is not being called properly. Any help would do great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct namespace?

Comment: I am using `use Symfony\Component\Serializer;`

Comment: That is not the class returned from `$this->container->get('serializer.normalizer.content_entity')`.

Comment: what should I use?

Comment: It's [`\Drupal\serialization\Normalizer\ContentEntityNormalizer`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21serialization%21src%21Normalizer%21ContentEntityNormalizer.php/class/ContentEntityNormalizer/8.2.x).

Comment: @kiamlaluno I tried but no success. I think I'm not calling the normalizer API correctly. What do you think?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43967/discussion-between-rakesh-verma-and-kiamlaluno).

Comment: I am not sure that is the correct service, and if the second parameter of `normalize()` is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried `serializer.normalizer.content_entity` but got no success in normalizing the (node) revision entity, or even node entity for that matter. It always resulted in the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function normalize() on a non-object in core/modules/serialization/src/Normalizer/ContentEntityNormalizer.php on line 28

For this I had to enable the serialization module. I also tried with the `ContentEntityNormalizer` provided by the "hal" module from core. Result same error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function normalize() on a non-object in core/modules/hal/src/Normalizer/ContentEntityNormalizer.php on line 95

I had success with directly using the `serializer` service from the serialization module. The working code for serializing a node revision is given below. It was verified on `/devel/php`

```
$revision = node_revision_load(4);
$container = \Drupal::getContainer();
$normalizer = $container->get('serializer');
$normalized_array = $serializer->normalize($revision);
dsm($normalized_array);
```

Or combine line 2 and 3 above to get the serializer directly as

```
$serializer = \Drupal::service('serializer');
```

In your `setup()` function, you need the following change:

```
$this->serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
```

P.S: I am still trying to figure out why `serializer.normalizer.content_entity` is not working and throwing the errors.

Comment: Yes, I think too that the correct service to use is the _serializer_ one. I cannot say why there are two services to serialize objects, but I would think that just one is the one that modules would use in their code.